# Searching a Google Books JSON object with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, object

I have fetched a list of books from Google Books API. I have saved the JSON object in localStorage, and then I have parsed it again in an object:

```
var books = JSON.parse(localStorage.books);
```

Now I want, based on book Id, to pull information for that particular book entry. I have managed to find the IDs for a specific book, showing them in a list, but is there any association of the ID of a book, and the rest of the information about that book? And if yes, how would you fetch all the data for a particular book from its id?

A JSON sample [Full API example of data](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/reference/volumes)

```
{
 "kind": "books#volume",
 "id": "HGsoQKfXs90C",
 "etag": "O6jaKOAAZvI",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/HGsoQKfXs90C",
 "volumeInfo": {
  "title": "John D. Rockefeller",
  "subtitle": "Anointed with Oil",
  "authors": [
   "Grant Segall"
  ],
  "publisher": "Oxford University Press",
  "publishedDate": "2001-02-08",
  "description": "Chronicles the life and accomplishments of the philanthropist and industrialist who founded the Standard Oil Company.",
  "industryIdentifiers": [
   {
    "type": "ISBN_10",
    "identifier": "0195121473"
   },
   {
    "type": "ISBN_13",
    "identifier": "9780195121476"
   }
  ],
  "pageCount": 128,
  "dimensions": {
   "height": "25.00 cm",
   "width": "23.10 cm",
   "thickness": "1.50 cm"
  },
```

Comment: @JeffS Why are you re-posting a link I have also posted on my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getBook(id){
    for(var i=0;i<books.items.length;i++){
        if(books.items[i].id === id){
            return books.items[i]; 
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var book = getBook('HGsoQKfXs90C');
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/reference/volumes/list - For reference, this would be the more appropriate Google Books API doc showing how the json is returned for the books.

Comment: I am not really good on JSON, or data structures in general. Is the id of a book, associated with the rest of the information about the book ?

Comment: Yes. This function shows that. If you pass an ID as shown, it returns the entire book object associated with that ID. In my example I search for the ID 'HGsoQKfXs90C' and store the matching book in the variable `book`. You can then refer to the `etag` property, for example, like: `book.etag`

Comment: That's the default return value in case your book is not found. The code only reaches that point if it does not find any book matching the ID in the loop. So if `book` is false instead of a book object, no match was found.